# Understanding function which inverts binary representation of even number

Tags: binary, inversion

I recently stumbled upon this function which inverts binary representation of even numbers,but I'm not able to understand the logic behind the code?

```
int binaryReverse(int toReverse) {

     int reversed = 0;
     while(toReverse > 0) {
             reversed *= 2;
             reversed += toReverse % 2;
             toReverse /= 2;
     }

     return reversed;
}
```

Comment: It works with odd numbers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't **invert** the bits, it **reverses** them (and only those between the rightmost bit and the leftmost bit which is set to 1).

Second, here is how it works:

```
int binaryReverse(int toReverse)
{
    int reversed = 0;
    while (toReverse > 0)
    {
        reversed  *= 2;             // shift the output one bit to the left
        reversed  += toReverse % 2; // set the rightmost bit in the output to the value of the rightmost bit in the input
        toReverse /= 2;             // shift the input one bit to the right
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Third, here is a possibly more readable version (though it has to take the input as `unsigned`):

```
int binaryReverse(unsigned int toReverse)
{
    int reversed = 0;
    while (toReverse > 0)
    {
        reversed  <<= 1;             // shift the output one bit to the left
        reversed   |= toReverse & 1; // set the rightmost bit in the output to the value of the rightmost bit in the input
        toReverse >>= 1;             // shift the input one bit to the right
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,sorry for using the wrong word .I am a noob to this site